Rocky Linux Proxypass url redirect
I have a VUE Nuxt-site with Nitro server hosted on a Rocky Linux running with PM2. The Nitro server is running on port 1344.
I have one site foo.se that has a proxy pass to the root and is working perfect.
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:1344/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:1344/

Second site bar.se is set to proxy to a subfolder
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:1344/dekaler
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:1344/dekaler

On first visit it shows the correct site for dekaler. It does however also change the URL to /dekaler direct without reload so it states bar.se/dekaler. If I reload I am redirected to bar.se/dekaler/dekaler
Im trying to figure out what is doing this redirect. Is it the proxypass doing this, or more likely something in my nuxt project?

Does the behavior change if you include a terminal / in your proxy targets (so http://127.0.0.1:1344/dekaler/ instead of http://127.0.0.1:1344/dekaler)?

No, it is same. I have chaganged to another subfolder in the proxy such as dekaler2 and the same behaviour is shown but with the new folder instead

adding a terminal / will also add the / to the URL so bar.se/dekaler/
